# After using Microsoft Outlook, none of my emails are on my iPhone, or Mac computer associated with my exchange account

Tags: email, sync, exchange

I used to access my exchange account from a couple different places, my iPhone, work Mac Pro, home MacBook Pro (using Apple Mail).

After installing Windows and Outlook, none of my emails are on my iPhone or Computers any more.

How do I get them back?

Thanks!

Things I've thought of/ tried:

Cached Exchange Mode might have been off when I first set up the account...

That's about it..

Comment: Also, the old emails aren't on the remote web email when I check for them.

Comment: Are the emails still there when you look in Outlook?

Comment: Yes, they are on the local computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled this phrase "put emails back on exchange server outlook".

I found this site: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34910484/put-messages-back-on-the-server.aspx

I went back into the Outlook and saw that I did indeed have two "Mailboxes". I just copied the mail from the "Personal Folders" Inbox, to the "Mailbox - My Name Here" Inbox.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

Enable IMAP in your email
Configure Outlook to sync with your mail via IMAP
Import your Outlook PST file into a Personal folder > File > Import And Export > Import from another program or file > Next > Personal Folder File (.pst) > Next > Select the PST file that contains your email, then Finish.
select the Personal folders that you want to backup online 
Folder view > right-click on the folder you want to copy > Copy Folder name
Click the mail folder in Outlook to copy that folder in that location.

This solution assumes your web mail allows IMAP.

Comment: So if I can get my exchange server to sync using IMAP, I can push the messages 'back' to the server this way?